# Parahoric subgroup over a local field

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, geometric-group-theory, buildings

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Let $F$ be a local field and $\mathcal{O}_{F}$ its valuation ring. Let $\pi\in \mathcal{O}_{F}$ be a uniformizer and $\mathfrak{p}=\pi\mathcal{O}_{F}$. Let $G$ be a split semisimple algebraic group over $F$. I think the case $G=\SL_{3}$ as an example. Let us consider a generator system $S=\{s_{1},s_{2},w_{1}\}$ of the affine Weyl group of $\SL_{3}(F)$, where
$$
s_{1}=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right),\quad
s_{2}=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0
\end{array}
\right),\quad
w_{1}=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & -\pi^{-1} \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\pi & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right).
$$
It is well-known that holds the affine Bruhat decomposition $\SL_{3}(F)=B\langle S\rangle B$ and $\SL_{3}(\mathcal{O}_{F})=B\langle s_{1},s_{2}\rangle B$ where $B$ is the standard Iwahori subgroup of $\SL_{3}(F)$.

Question: What is the remaining component $B\langle w_{1}\rangle B=B\cup Bw_{1}B$? I want to know the explicit form of this subgroup.

Comment: By the way, the more usual term than "affine parabolic" is "parahoric".

Comment: What do you mean by "remaining component"? We don't have $\langle s_1, s_2 , w_1 \rangle = \langle s_1, s_2 \rangle \cup \langle w_1 \rangle$.

Comment: Sorry. The term of  "remaining component" had no special meaning. I understand that $\langle S\rangle \neq \langle s_{1},s_{2} \rangle\cup \langle w_{1}\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\newcommand\O{\mathcal O_F}\newcommand\P{\pi\mathcal O_F}\newcommand\Pi{\pi^{-1}\mathcal O_F}$I assume that the standard Iwahori is the group of matrices in $\SL_3(\O)$ that are upper triangular modulo $\pi$.  Then $B \cup Bw_1 B$ is
$K \mathrel{:=} \begin{pmatrix} \O & \O & \Pi \\ \P & \O & \O \\ \P & \P & \O \end{pmatrix} \cap \SL_3(F)$.

Indeed, it is clear that this is a subgroup, that it contains (hence is stable under left- and right-multiplication by) $B$, and that it contains $w_1$.  Therefore, it contains $B \cup Bw_1 B$.

On the other hand, suppose $\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & \pi^{-1} c \\ \pi d & e & f \\ \pi g & \pi h & i \end{pmatrix}$ belongs to $K$ (so that $a, \dotsc, i$ belong to $\O$).  If $c$ belongs to $\P$, then $\gamma$ belongs to $B$.  Otherwise, $b \mathrel{:=} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ & 1 \\ \pi i/c && 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $(b w_1)^{-1}\gamma$ both belong to $B$, so $\gamma$ belongs to $B w_1 B$.

Comment: Did you mean to intersect with $SL_3(F)$ rather than $SL_3(\mathcal O_F)$?

Comment: @WillSawin, [yes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419750/affine-parabolic-subgroup-over-a-local-field/419775#comment1078037_419775), thanks; edited.